# É possivel coletar a quantidade de dados gastos em um período de tempo?

Tags: android

Estou fazendo uma aplicação Android e preciso pegar a quantidade de dados utilizados pela pessoa em um período de tempo específico, em Androids que usam as APIs level 21(lollipop) até a atual(Nougat).

Eu pesquisei e encontrei duas classes, uma delas é a TrafficStats que através dela eu posso pegar toda a quantidade de dados gasto desde o boot do celular, ou seja, toda vez que o celular é desligado e ligado o valor retornado vai para zero, esta classe é suportada pelas APIs 21+(lollipop). Então para fazer a coleta corretamente o meu app precisaria sempre ficar funcionado o que não acontece sempre, pois o usuário pode escolher fecha-lo.

A outra classe é a NetworkStatsManager que faz exatamente o que preciso, mas só funciona para APIs 23+(Marshmallow).

Então, existe alguma outra classe ou ferramenta que eu possa utilizar que funcione de forma parecida com o NetworkStatsManager mas que é compatível com versões do Android anteriores?

Comment: Estou longe de ser um profundo conhecedor do assunto. Mas mesmo assim queria dar uma sugestão/dica: mesmo a sua APP não sendo executada todas as vezes, você pode guardar o valor obtido de `TrafficStats` em cada execução. Assim, quando a APP for aberta novamente, você consegue comparar o valor atual e o anterior e interpolar a variação entre esses intervalos para *estimar* o tráfego em qualquer período de tempo. Dessa forma, o usuário vai ter um resultado melhor quanto mais ele usa a sua APP, mas mesmo assim consegue ter uma resposta aproximada mesmo que use pouco.